# How to run a maven project/main class in netbeans without building first?

Tags: java, netbeans, maven

I have a maven project in the latest version of Netbeans but due to an undetermined problem with my environment/maven setup I have to build the project from the command line using gmake as building with mvn clean install comes up with a lot of errors.

So, I was wondering as I'm building from the command line, when using netbeans to run the project/main class, how can I just run it without it building/compiling first - i.e. every time I right click the main class and select run file - its will say - 'Building...' - can I just run the file without building/compiling?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not found a way to run this in Netbeans, but as a workaround am running the project from the command line using:

mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.rory.djgx.server.Main"

Just need to ensure this is executed in the root directory of the compiled classes (.class), e.g. com/rory/djgx and that the pom.xml is in this root directory.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just run the Build / Compile have an option to use all the powers of the Build Phases, as Validate, Build, Test, Package, Integration, Test, Verify, Install or Deploy. To do this you must:

-Right Click on Project -> Custom -> Goals ...

-In the Goals you can choose the more specifically option choice to build whatever you want, like Compile, Deploy, etc...

Comment: Could you please explain it further? Every time I run maven project from Netbeans it has to build first. Even with no changes, I just can't only re-run it. Could I skip building with your solution?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe too late to answer but I had the same problem today with NetBeans 11.

You can configure this with right click on the given project and select "**Properties**" at the bottom of the popup menu. You need to select the "**Actions**" category and then select the "**Run file via main()**" action.

**The original properties**

*Execute Goals*:

```
process-classes org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec
```

*Set properties*:

```
exec.args=-classpath %classpath ${packageClassName}
exec.executable=java
exec.classpathScope=${classPathScope}
```

**You need to change both of them**

*Execute Goals*:

```
process-classes org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java
```

*Set properties*:

```
exec.mainClass=${packageClassName}
exec.cleanupDaemonThreads=false
exec.classpathScope=compile
```

*I have also changed the version (and the executed goal as well) of the maven-exec-plugin to 1.6.0*

After saving the new configuration with the OK button you can right click on the edited java file and select "Run File" and the public static void main(String[] args) method will be executed.

I also attach the NetBeans screen for reference:

[image]